# simple uart code doen't work

Tags: stm32

I wrote simple uart transmit and receive functions(for serial communication between PC and stm32f4 discovery board). I am using usart4 on the board and a usb to serial converter to create a virtual COM port. Aso, when any character is received from terminal , an LED connected to PC1 must light up. But neither the transmit nor receive functionalities seem to work and i cant figure why.

The folowing is my code:

```
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"
//#include "cmsis_os.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_hal_uart.h"
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

#include "rt_misc.h"

#ifdef __DBG_ITM
volatile int32_t ITM_RxBuffer;
#endif

void SER_Init (void){
    #ifdef __DBG_ITM
    ITM_RxBuffer=ITM_RXBUFFER_EMPTY;
    #else
    RCC->APB1ENR|=(1UL<<19);//Enable USART 4 clock
    //RCC->APB2ENR|=(1UL<<4);//Enable USART 1 clock
    RCC->AHB1ENR|=(1UL<<2);//Enable GPIOC clock
    GPIOC->MODER &=0XFF0FFFFF;
    GPIOC->MODER |=0X00A00000;
    GPIOC->MODER |=0X00000008;
    GPIOC->AFR[1]|=0X00008800;//PC10 UART4_Tx, PC11 UART4_Rx (Connect RX of xbee to pc10 of board, TX to PC11)
    UART4->BRR=0x1117;

    UART4->CR1=0X200C;//    setting data word , enabling uart(UE), enable tx,rx(TE,RE)
    UART4->CR1 |= 0x0020; // Enable RX interrupt//RXNIE=1
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(UART4_IRQn); // Enable IRQ for UART4 in NVIC 
    #endif
}
int data1,data2;

    int32_t UART4_IRQHandler(void)     {   
  // RX IRQ part 
        data1=SER_GetChar();
        if(data1)
            GPIOC->BSRR=(1<<1);

} 
int32_t SER_PutChar (int32_t ch){
//  #ifdef __DBG_ITM
//  int i;
//  ITM_SendChar (ch&0xFF);
//  for(i=10000,i,i--)
//      ;
//  #else   
    while (!(UART4->SR& 0X0080));

    UART4->SR&= 0XFFBF;
        UART4->DR=(ch &0xFF);
//  #endif

    return(ch);
}
int32_t SER_GetChar (void){
    #ifdef __DBG_ITM
if(ITM_CheckChar())
    return ITM_ReceiveChar();
#else
if(UART4->SR&0X0020)
    return (UART4->DR);
    #endif

    return(-1);
}
void wait(unsigned long delay);
void wait (unsigned long delay){
    unsigned long i;
    for (i=0;i<delay;i++)
    ;
}
//#########################Clock Configuration#################
void SystemClock_Config(void) {
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;

  /* Enable Power Control clock */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* The voltage scaling allows optimizing the power consumption when the
     device is clocked below the maximum system frequency (see datasheet). */
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  /* Enable HSE Oscillator and activate PLL with HSE as source */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 25;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 336;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 7;
  HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct);

  /* Select PLL as system clock source and configure the HCLK, PCLK1 and PCLK2
     clocks dividers */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1 |
                                RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_5);
}
//########################################################
 int  received_string;
    int st;
int arg;
 int i=0;
char ch='c';
int count=20;
char buffer[20];
    int main (void){
    char a[100]="Testing!",b[100];

    SystemClock_Config();
    SER_Init();
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
  while(!(UART4->SR& 0X0080));
        SER_PutChar (ch);

        }
    while(1){
        printf("Sending Data");


    }}
```

Comment: The simplest test is to check the connections. RX must connect to TX and viceversa

Comment: yes i have ensured this is done right. The problem seems to be something else, may be in the code

Comment: Do you have a scope to check if the signals are doing what you expect?

Comment: Using RC oscillator then PLL is usually not a good idea when doing any form of serial communication. You need to ensure that you get sufficient baudrate accuracy. This isn't the source of your problem, but could become a different problem.

Comment: I wanted to know if the code i wrote has anything missing or something is incorrect?